# SAS Substringing inside of a macro

Tags: macros, sas

I have a sample code that works in a data step (outside of a macro) but it doesn't work when I try to convert it to a macro. I have tried different types of ways to do it with CALL SYMPUTS, SYSFUNC, LETs, etc.. The code listed below is what I'm trying to make into a macro that inputs the T_Test2.

```
DATA asdhjkl;
    SET T_Test2;
    IF INPUT(SCAN(COL1, 1, "-"), best.)=0 THEN COL1=SUBSTR(COL1, INDEX(COL1,"-")+1);
    string="-00000000000000000000";
    DO I = 1 TO 20;
        COL1 = TRANWRD(COL1, trim(string), " ");
        string = substr(string, 1, length(string)-1);
        PUT string;
    END;
    COL1=COMPRESS(COL1);
RUN;
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is substring variations of "-0" out of another string such as 65-03 and removing the 03. But it's also more general so it can work if it's 65-003 and 65-0003, etc.

Comment: Please add sample input data and expected results.  Also explain how you plan to use this in a macro.  Why not just have the macro generate the same SAS code you have already shown if you know that works?

Comment: So your strings can be broken into parts separated by hyphens?  How many parts can each string have? Is it always two parts?  Can each individual part be converted into an integer? Or could they include non-digit characters? Could any part be longer than 15 digits?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert values like your examples of `65-003` and `65-003` to `65-3` then your program is way too complex.  You could just convert the second part to a number and then generate the string.  Or you could use regular expressions to convert hyphens followed by one or more zeros into just a hyphen.

Here is data step code solution for both methods:

```
data test;
  input have $20. ;
  length want1-want2 $20;
  want1=catx('-',scan(have,1,'-'),input(scan(have,2,'-'),32.));
  want2=prxchange('s/-0*/-/',-1,have);
cards;
65-003
65-0003
;
```

Or you can do something similar in macro code to operate on the value of a macro variable.  The `%eval()` function evaluate strings that look like expressions using integer arithmetic, so adding the `+` makes the `003` look like an expression to be evaluated.

```
%macro fix1(string);
%scan(&string,1,-)-%eval(+%scan(&string,2,-))
%mend fix1;

%macro fix2(string);
%sysfunc(prxchange(s/-0*/-/,-1,%superq(string)))
%mend fix2;

%put %fix1(65-003);
```

Comment: If you could, could you explain how the first macro works. Like how does that work.

Also how would you make these macros work because if I attempt to input any trying in there, it spits out "Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order."

Comment: I added an example usage. The macro just emit strings so use those strings anywhere else you could use a string, like `%let` or inside double quotes as part of a SAS statement..